# Isn't storing all of its data as strings an overhead in terms of memory usage?

Tags: redis, heap-memory

1. Isn't storing only strings as data type a big overhead in terms of memory consumption? 
   e.g.: To store "304.2" in any application is more expensive than to store 304.2 as float/double.
2. Even if internally the value is indeed stored as a numeric value, delegating to every client the responsibility of "parsing" the string isn't  another source of inefficiency?

I was getting super excited to start using redis but my case of usage is to cache a key x value structure like "string" x "doubles[]". Even if it would probably pay off in comparison with disk those two points really turns me off in adopting the technology. 
I would love to be proven wrong, this is why I'm asking the question.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For point 1: You *can't* store 304.2 as a float/double; you can only store a close approximation to it. To store it, you need e.g. a dedicated decimal type, or more general rational type. Or a string.

For point 2:

> [RESP is a compromise between the following things:](https://redis.io/topics/protocol)
>
> - Simple to implement.
> - Fast to parse.
> - Human readable.

Human readable means that no matter how numbers are stored internally, they still would be sent as strings and clients would have to parse them.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. When I asked about storing the 304.2 I was implying a regular floating point representation with the desired number of bytes. From the compromise in point 2 i think the only one relevat is the "simple to implement". But I'm still not satisfied with the answer. Would it be that difficult to also implement floating point numbers and integers?!? As far as I know other caching systems like Infinispan do all of the job...

Answer (score 0):

After all I've chosen Infinispan which gave me the APIs was looking for. Pros of the choosen solution is the actual ability to refer to the cache as a generic key x value concurrent map. Cons: probably less flexible in terms of out of the box client supported programming languages, even though you can always use google protobuff.